# how can i take json data and read it into javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, object

how can i take this json data (either from website or pasted into local file) and read it into a javascript object?

Here is the json data: https://jsonblob.com/b914b62a-e276-11e7-8a9c-f99a86745e2b

Comment: what language you working on? node.js? browser? angular?

Comment: i have a basic notepad file saved as a .js file on the desktop. by executing that file through the node command prompt i want it to read the json file shown in the url

Comment: this is what i tried so far:   <script>
  var scene={};
  $.getJSON('hello.json', function(data) { 
    scene=data;
  }); 
</script>

Comment: var requestURL = 'https://jsonblob.com/b914b62a-e276-11e7-8a9c-f99a86745e2b';

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', requestURL);

request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload = function() {
  var data= request.response;
  populateHeaderdata
  showHeroes(data);
}     this is what i tried and i got "xmlhttprequest is not defined". Maybe because it's not a json file on the website...

Comment: sorry i don't know how to paste proper code format on here

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an JSON file to an object by using JSON.parse

```
let convertedObject = JSON.parse(text)
```

Comment: thank you very much. i am very new to this. so what would be the complete code from start to finish and how would i run it by using the a node command as such: >node file.js ?? ....    If i have the js file with the code saved in the desktop i can just use node to run the js file right? and that can read the .json file saved in the desktop as well and store it as a js object?

Answer (score 0):

There are not many differences between a JSON string and a Javascript Object. In fact Everything is an object in javascript, from functions to arrays...well coming back to your question you can get the value stored in a JSON string by parsing the JSON string by using `JSON.parse()` function and then call it as you generally do with JS objects. for Example: -

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({key: "val"}); // here i am converting a regular object to JSON string
var jsonToObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(jsonToObj.key);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am very new to this and am working through an exercise. which of these lines specifies the destination of the file or url where there json file is located?

Comment: Hello Enil Bro...if you are new to JS and planning to work around JSON or JSON-based Databases,these two functions `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` are two of very basic functions and you should learn about them first. and the json file is actually an object in this example which is converted to a JSON string by using the 'stringify' method(ref. to var jsonString). I hope you got your doubts clear here. GOOD LUCK BRO!